# Pad zeros to the right in Dates.now()

Tags: julia

I do some simple logging by means of:

```
 println("*** ", Dates.now(), " READ CSV")
```

But depending on timestamp I got that last value of the timestamp can be omitted if zero (see third log message, 470 is displayed as 47):

```
*** 2019-09-14T15:44:59.862 READ CSV
*** 2019-09-14T15:45:08.065 PARSE DATETIME
*** 2019-09-14T15:45:10.47 ROUND DOWN PRICES TO CONTRACT TICKS
```

While it is not a big deal, I am still wondering how this would be fixed in Julia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to use the `rpad` function:

```
println("*** ", rpad(Dates.now(), 23, "0"), " READ CSV")
```